# Structured cloning - which thread does the clone?

Tags: javascript, structured-clone

I have some work being done on a WebWorker. When I post an object back to my GUI thread, the Javascript engine uses the structured cloning algorithm to clone the object with the GUI thread receiving a cloned object.

My question is, where is the cloning work being done, on the sender (WebWorker), receiver (GUI thread), both, or have I got completely the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: `webworkers` it should have to be at client.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send message width cloned data. And as there is no communication between threads except postMessages, there is no way receiver can perform structured cloning.
SO cloning work is implemented on thread that sends a message.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers Transferring data to and from workers: further details